# Finding the Sum of Dictionary Keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary with a number value in both the keys and the value like so:

```
d = {22:13,14:38,26:18}
```

How would I go about finding the sum of all of the keys in that dictionary?

Answer (score 4):

```
sum(d)
```

It's really as easy as that.

Comment: Actually it's as easy as `sum(d)`

Comment: When I try that, I get an error that 'd' is undefined. edit: I am a fool. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: Your dictionary is called `d` in your post. It must be there.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this.

```
D1={1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'} 
total = 0
for k, v in D1.items():
   total = total + k
print(total)
```

Answer (score -1):

here is another method, and this works:

```
d = {22:13,14:38,26:18}
l1 = [i for i in d]
print(sum(l1))
```